# Having one docker file for multiple containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi I have three repos each of them having docker-compose files with respective ports and need to have one docker compose file that would stand all these containers up. Is it possible to do so? I am quite new to docker and have exhauseted all searches online. Thanks in advance

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: container-name
    restart: always
    build: ./
    ports: "8085":8085
  stub:
    container_name: test-stub
    restart: always
    build: ./
    ports: "8086":8086
```

Comment: Could you include your docker-compose files and show what you tried so far? See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Is it necessary to use docker-compose for this? You can just write a script that git pulls the three repositories and then run the docker-compose commands for them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

In the build option you can specify which dockerfile to use :

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_service:
    container_name: my_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: my_container.Dockerfile
```